# How to return NaN from a select statement?

Tags: sql-server, decimal

I want to write a query that returns the decimal value NaN (Not a Number) in a column of a SELECT statement.

I've tried `select 0/0` but that return a division by zero error instead of one row having the value NaN.

Comment: You should return `NULL` instead.

Comment: There is the possibility that SQL Server doesn't support it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/50340/MSSQL-doesn-t-completely-support-IEEE-floating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. SQL Server has no support for NAN. Null is the only "special value" supported. This IS problematic - but it is as it is.

Comment: Exactly. Here's the corresponding Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/239674/storing-ieee-754-floats-in-sql-server-2005-nan-infinity

Answer (score 0):

It is supported in SSRS.
If you do the division in SSRS you will get NaN

Comment: How would I access SSRS functionality in a SELECT statement?